# Logging configuration global LogLevel is not honored in appsettings.json

Tags: logging, asp.net-core

**Context**

The logging is in place and working in my ASP.NET Core web application. It works (including constructor injection) out of the box when using `CreateDefaultBuilder`. (which configures logging via reading `appsettings.json` "Logging" section.)

**Question**

Is it the expected behavior what I am experiencing, see below, or am I missing something? If this is the expected behavior, then what's the use of the "global" LogSettings section?

**What I have tried so far**

I am trying to configure LogLevel, but is **seems to be ignored**, all level events are showing up on Console:

```
"Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Warning",
   "System": "Warning",
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
   "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
 },
 "Console": {
  "IncludeScopes": true
 },
```

However if I add a LogLevel section especially under Console **it works correctly:**

```
"Logging": {
 "LogLevel": {
   "Default": "Warning",
   "System": "Warning",
   "Microsoft": "Warning",
   "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
 },
 "Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning",
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
  },
  "IncludeScopes": true
 },
```